# What is symfony in the vendor folder?

Tags: symfony, laravel, composer-php

When I create an app using composer, or install another app created using composer, there is a vendor/symfony folder included.

For example, I installed Laravel using composer. The folder vendor/symfony is present. I am not specifically referencing this in my Laravel app at all.

What is this folder, and it needed? Does the app use it, or composer use it? So if I am using an app created using Composer and dont use composer myself, can it safely be deleted and the app still run? Or could the app be using it?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Answer is quite simple: Laravel uses Symfony components.

Check this article: http://www.sitepoint.com/build-php-framework-symfony-components/

> **Improved Routing Engine**
>
> Laravel 4.1 features a totally re-written routing layer. The API is
>   the same; however, registering routes is a full 100% faster compared
>   to 4.0. The entire engine has been greatly simplified, and the
>   dependency on **Symfony Routing** has been minimized to the compiling of
>   route expressions.
>
> http://laravel.com/docs/master/releases

Answer (score 1):

The "vendor" folder is a standard in every application / framework that uses composer to manage dependencies. In the "vendor" folder you will find all dependencies (read: libraries) that your applicatication requires.

But you will also find **all libraries that your libraries require**. In order to minimize code duplication, and thanks to the composer system, most open source projects now reuse parts from other open source projects.

BTW, this is great.

Symfony components are excellent and well documented, so they are currently used by many other frameworks and applications.

Inside the "vendor" you may find other libraries that you did not specifically require yourself, but as long as your correctly use composer, that's not something you should worry about.

Comment: Thanks, I am familiar with the vendor folder, and can see others in there the app needs, but the symfony one is in EVERY app that I use that has composer.